# Is it possible to run .php files on my local computer?

Tags: php, local

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP server on local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678010/php-server-on-local-machine)

Is it possible to run .php files on my local computer? I know if i open up a web browser and enter the file location into the URL for HTML files, the html file will run and display. Is there a way to do the same with .php files?

Comment: Install XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for a local development environment.

Comment: You need a web server running on your local computer. There are many packages for different platforms that make this easy to setup...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure you just need to setup a local web server. Check out XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

That will get you up and running in about 10 minutes.

There is now a way to run php locally without installing a server:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21872484/672229

Comment: I appreciate the help, but i am on a mac and i cannot run that software. Is there anything else that i would be able to use? Thank you!

Comment: then use MAMP: http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Comment: XAMPP runs on OSX, what OS are you running @StevenRogers ?

Comment: I am running OS X Version 10.6.8.

Just downloaded the program, trying it right now.

Comment: Because this is the #1 result on Google, I thought I'd add that there is actually a way to start a local server without any software installation: `cd path/to/your/app` and then `php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: @bencodezen you should add your comment as an answer. most simple and fast solution.

Comment: @LukeSchoenberger Sadly I'm unable to do so since it was closed 8 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but the files need to be processed. For example you can install test servers like mamp / lamp / [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/) depending on your plateform.

Basically you need apache / php running.