# Error on submit form with Start Bootstrap "Agency" theme

Tags: javascript, php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I usually work in Rails and I'm trying out PHP for the first time. I'm using a Start Bootstrap template ([Agency](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/)) and can't seem to get the Contact Me form to submit correctly. I defined a recipient email for submissions in the PHP file. When I run it locally, fill out the form, and click submit, I get the fail message from the contact_me.js file.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050776/bootstrap-theme-php-email-form-not-working) is similar and received no answers. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated. Thank you!

contact_me.php

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if (empty($_POST['name']) ||
    empty($_POST['email']) ||
    empty($_POST['phone']) ||
    empty($_POST['message']) ||
    !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
) {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'RemovedEmailForStackOverflow@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.

$email_subject = "A guest has messaged yourname:  $name";

$email_body = "You've received a message from your website contact form.\n\n" . "Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";

$headers = "From: noreply@gmail.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

return true;
?>
```

contact_me.js

```
$(function() {

    $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Thank you! We'll be in touch very soon. If you'd like to make a reservation in the meantime, please find us on Expedia. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>So sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that our mail server is not responding. Please call us while we resolve this issue. ");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

index.html

```
<!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Contact Us</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-contact">U.S. phone: (555) 555-5555</h3>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-contact">Panama phone: (555)-555-5555 </h3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running PHP locally on your machine with WAMP or XAMPP (Windows) or MAMP (Mac). You need to run PHP on your local machine in order to execute the script. The issue may be that your PHP is not being executed.

This thread may be helpful if that's the issue: [Is it possible to run .php files on my local computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318858/is-it-possible-to-run-php-files-on-my-local-computer)

Comment: Downloading and installing MAMP now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As @digitally suggested, the error was that I was not running PHP locally on my machine, so the script was not executing. Everything works fine when I use my app on the web.