# How to set rand(1,100) to always true(above 20)?

Tags: php

I'd like to know if this stands correctly, I am wanting to set rand(1,100) to be 100 for specific pages and I'm unsure if I have done it correctly..

```
$rand = rand(1, 100);

if( basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') == 'index' ) #index.php
{   
    $rand = 100;
}

if ($rand > 20)
{
    echo 'Yes it works';
} else {
    echo 'no it does not work';
}
```

So if index.php loads, will $rand be set to 100 always with the if statement that I wrote? or would it need to be `$rand > 100;`

Comment: This should work, yes, though it is strange. Have you tested it out, though? That is the best way to find out.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: He probably wants to walk on the moon but doesn't know what the moon looks like so it doesn't matter if he's there or not, he won't be sure if he has succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

`$rand` will always be `100` when the requested file is `index.php` (no matter the path, i.e /index.php or /some/path/index.php).

There is also a chance that `$rand` will be `100` even when it is not `index.php` that was requested, due to the parameters passed to the `rand()` function call.

This can be easily tested: [PHP server on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678010/php-server-on-local-machine)