# Running HTML file locally with PHP backend

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a small program which HTML and javascript in front end and PHP backend. The javascript sends POST to PHP to create, update tasks. So i want to run the program locally as there are some issues to be resolved. However when i run, it does not do the create task and results in error:
[image]

IS there anything i need to do get this running.
Thanks in advance.
Edit:
Adding a portion of javascript code to POST to php page:

```
$.post("model.php", {
            'task': 'write',
            'elementname': door
        }).done(function () {
            location.href = '?' + door;
        });
```

[image]

Installed XAMPP but getting the following error:

Comment: Please give more info!!, What are you tring to do, and show some code!

Comment: @VasylYovdiy Added to post.

Comment: Run your code with an e.g. local Apache Server like xampp and it will work. The error is writen in your console "blocked by CORS policy" (default Browser security)

Comment: @Richard I have installed XAMPP and now its running. But still i get the same error in my console. I am new to the php thing and i have a doubt regarding how to load the HTML file. I just opened my local file. Is there a different way to run the html file when using the server? Could you please guide on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you tring to execute php code without having a server and this is not posible.

You should install XAMP or something similar.

Also there is now a way to run php locally without installing a server:

[PHP server on local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678010/php-server-on-local-machine/21872484#21872484)

Comment: I tried installing XAMPP but unable to run Apache. Attached screenshot to post

Comment: I would recoment to reinstall XAMP following some tutorial step by step!

Try this one for Windows: https://blog.templatetoaster.com/install-xampp-on-windows/

Comment: I got it workinng finally. Found a useful video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjFRTkw6GDQ

Comment: Thanks to all suggesting installation of server.. running html with php backend was new to me..