# Passing a POST call through AJAX to a PHP file returns 404

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is the JS:

```js
function sendEmail(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $name = $('#name');
  var $email = $('#email');
  var $phone = $('#phone');
  var $message = $('#message');

  if (isNotEmpty($name) && isNotEmpty($email) && isNotEmpty($phone) && isNotEmpty($message)) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'sendEmail.php',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        name: $name.val(),
        email: $email.val(),
        phone: $phone.val(),
        message: $message.val()
      }, success: function (response){
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The browser says *sendEmail.php* is not found.
`jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/sendEmail.php 404 (Not Found)`

This is the folder structure of my project:

[image: Folder structure of my project]

The **js** code is from the file `assets/mail/contact_form.js` and the `sendEmail.php` is at the *src* folder.

Comment: Which php page are you running the JS in? Remember that the path needs to be relative to the exectuing page, not the .js file

Comment: The js is being run from ```index.html``` which is in the dist folder (not shown here).

Comment: Then you need to update the path relative from index.html - or better yet make every path relative to the root of the site by prefixing it with ```/```, eg. `/sendEmail.php`, assuming the `src` folder is the root

Comment: I've tried changing the URL to ```'/sendEmail.php'``` but the error still occurs.

Comment: Unfortunately that's all the help that can be provided with the information shown. All we can tell you is that the path is wrong, and what you need to do to fix it

Comment: Did you try to open this URL in your browser ?http://localhost:3000/sendEmail.php

Comment: Pls open in your browser http://localhost:3000/assets/sendEmail.php

Comment: I have copied the ```sendEmail.php``` file into the dist folder and now visiting ```localhost:3000/sendEmail.php ``` downloads the ```sendEmail.php``` file

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is outside of the information you shared, so I'll try my best to guess at what's going on, and hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

#### How are you compiling your code?

You have a `src/` directory. Somehow, your computer compiles the files in the `src/` directory and outputs the results into the `dist/` directory. For example, `src/pug/index.pug` becomes `dist/index.html`.

When you run your webserver, if `dist/index.html` is available at `http://localhost:3000`, then the `dist/` folder is your public root. Look in the `dist/` folder. Is `sendEmail.php` in there? My guess is, it's not.

This brings us back to the question of "how are you compiling your code?". However you're doing it, perhaps a command line tool, you'll want to add a step in which you copy over the missing files. You could do this by configuring your compiler to include the missing php files, or you could do it manually via the command line:

```sh
cp src/sendEmail.php dist
```

Hope that helps. If you provide details on what compiler/framework/server/etc you're running, the community will be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: are you using a PHP server? You'll need to run some code to make your computer deliver the PHP to the browser. Perhaps instead of the current server you're running, after compiling, you can run `cd dist && php -S localhost:3000` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678010/php-server-on-local-machine for more

Comment: Also, it may not matter but it's best-practice to keep URLs lowercase, so I also suggest renaming the php file to something like `send-email.php`

Comment: It's a node.js server that I am running and like you mentioned, I will take a look at how the code is being compiled. The file might be ignored somewhere.

Comment: Hmm the thing is, the node.js server won't interpret the php -- you'll need to run the php server (which will also serve your html and js files), or, instead of using php scripts, you can write your server-side scripts in js and use a node.js server like https://expressjs.com/ to serve them