# Creating a calendar using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to php and really have no clue what I am doing. I am trying to make the calendar 4 rows across and 4 columns wide. So one month per row and column. For example January, February, March and April will consist of row 2 columns. I'm not even sure how to get started.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lq0Y.jpg) for an example.

This is what i have so far

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column";">
        <h2>LOGO GOES HERE</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column";">
        <h2>2021</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>2021</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>2021</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>January</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">

        <h2>February</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>March</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>April</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>May</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>June</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>July</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>August</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <h2>September</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>October</h2> –

    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>November</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>December</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean you want a single page to display 16 months ? (4 rows X 4 columns, each cell a single month ?)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am seeking help with.

Comment: This crosses many languages, specifically HTML, CSS and PHP. Do you need something that crosses all of these or do you have a start? It is also rare for a need this specific without mixing in HTTP, specifically forms, and probably JS. Are these needed to?

Comment: So I do have experience with HTML and CSS. I a not sure where to start.

Comment: So would I make the calendar in HTML and CSS and then incorporate the PHP? If so how would I incorporate it?

Comment: Further to my answer below, you'll likely need to set up a local PHP server on your machine. There's a lot out there on this and it will depend on your operating system, but a tool called XAMPP is popular. Alternatively, you can run a local PHP server on your machine [using the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678010/php-server-on-local-machine)

Comment: Yes I have downloaded Xampp

Comment: Please provide a specific, less broad, question, along with the work you have already done. Saying that you do not know where to start with makes it sound like you did not try any options before asking.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option would be to use the built-in HTML `date` element, which adds a calendar view when users click it. This is the example provided in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

```
<label for="start">Start date:</label>

<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
```

To get the value in a form using PHP you'd do something like the below. Save this into a file called `index.php`:

```
<form action="get-date.php" method="POST">

  <label for="start">Start date:</label>

  <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Now create a file called `get-date.php` in the same folder and add the following:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $date = $_POST['trip-start'];
      echo $date;
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain html code, you could build with tables code. You could use php to iterate on 4 rows over 4 columns, and for each table, thead for dayNames, tr for each week.

```
<?php 
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) { 
 for($j=0; $j<4; $j++) { ?>
   <table><!-- for each month -->
     <thead>
       <th>MON</th><th>TUES</th><th>WED</th><th>THURS</th>
       <th>FRI</th><th>SAT</th><th>SUN</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr><!--iterate over weeks for month-->
         <td></td><!--iterate over days for the week-->
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: So I have it coded it by I am not sure how to incorporate the PHP code you gave the example above.

Comment: This is what I have.

<?php 
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) { 
 for($j=0; $j<4; $j++) { ?>
   <table><h2>January</h2><h2>February</h2><h2>March</h2><h2>April</h2><h2>May</h2><h2>June</h2><h2>July</h2><h2>August</h2><h2>September</h2><h2>October</h2><h2>November</h2><h2>December</h2>
     <thead>
       <th>Mo</th><th>Tu</th><th>We</th><th>Th</th>
       <th>Fr</th><th>Sa</th><th>Su</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr><!--iterate over weeks for month-->
         <td></td><!--iterate over days for the week-->
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
<?php } } ?>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you:

1. Choose your start date - you could use a php function for today's date
2. Iterate over 4 rows and for each over 4 columns
3. Display the month and year for each of the subsequent months
4. For each month open a table and table head to display the days' label
5. For each each week for that month put in a table row and the day of month number in the corresponding table cell.
   Try to follow through in the code below:

   ```
        <div style="width:100%; padding:0; margin:2%;"> 
        <?php
        for($j=0; $j<4; $j++) { 
        ?> <!--column of 4 rows -->
            <div style="width:22%; float:left; margin:1%; padding:0;"><!<!-- row of 4 months -->
                <h4><?=date('F Y', strtotime($date));?></h4>
                <table><!<!-- for each month -->
                    <thead><th>M</th><th>T</th><th>W</th><th>T</th><th>F</th><th>S</th><th>S</th></thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        for($m = date('m',strtotime($date)); 
                            $m == date('m', strtotime($date)); 
                            $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))) { ?>
                        <!-- for each week -->
                        <tr>
                            <?php if(date('w',strtotime($date))!=1) { ?>
                            <td colspan="<?=(date('w',strtotime($date))+6)%7;?>"></td> <?php } ?>
                            <?php
                            for($wkNo = date('W',strtotime($date)); 
                                $wkNo == date('W',strtotime($date)); 
                                $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date)+$plus1day)) {
                                    if($m != date('m',strtotime($date))) { break;}
                                    ?>
                                <!--for each day -->
                                <td style="width:3%"><?=date('d',strtotime($date));?></td>
                         <?php } ?><!--end of week-->                  
                        </tr>   
                    <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        <?php    } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
   ```